# Get the GTK Window from which a Clipboard signal_owner_change originated (Gtkmm)

Tags: c++, linux, gtk, clipboard, gtkmm

My application needs to listen to clipboard changes to record them. I can currently achieve that with a `signal_owner_change` callback which then requests the contents of the clipboard. However, I need to figure out which window the event originated from, so that I can ignore when a user copies text from the application itself (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, not programmatically).

The `signal_owner_change` callback takes a `GdkEventOwnerChange*` as a parameter, which contains the fields `owner` and `window` of type `GdkWindow*`.

- The field `owner` changes for each different application / window I copy from, but never corresponds to the window pointer of my application.
- The field `window` is always the same, but also does not match my application window.

Unfortunately, the GTK+ documentation is very unclear about what the "owner" and the "window" of a GdkEventOwnerChange is, or how to exploit the data.

My application window is a class inheriting from `Gtk::ApplicationWindow`. I get the `GdkWindow*` as such:

```cpp
GdkWindow* win = gtk_widget_get_window(GTK_WIDGET(gobj()));
```

Here is an extract of the clipboard owner change even handler: (in another class, which gets the window pointer above as `parentWindow`)

```cpp
MyNamespace::MyClass::MyClass(GdkWindow* parentWindow)
    : parentWindow(parentWindow) {
  // setup UI, etc...

  clipboard = Gtk::Clipboard::get();
  clipboard->signal_owner_change().connect(
      sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyClass::on_clipboard_owner_change));
}

void MyNamespace::MyClass::on_clipboard_owner_change(GdkEventOwnerChange* event) {
  std::cout << "Owner: " << event->owner
            << ", window: " << event->window
            << ", parent: " << parentWindow
            << std::endl;

  // This does not work
  if (event->owner == parentWindow)
    return;

  switch (get_clipboard_content_type()) {
    case ClipboardDataType::Text: {
      clipboard->request_text(
          sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyClass::on_clipboard_text_received));
      break;
    }
    case ClipboardDataType::Image: {
      std::cout << "Image is available, unimplemented handler" << std::endl;
      break;
    }
    case ClipboardDataType::URIs: {
      std::cout << "URIs is available, unimplemented handler" << std::endl;
      break;
    }
    default: {
      std::cout << "Unknown or unsupported clipboard data type" << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the console output:

```
# Copy from another application
Owner: 0x5571ec44dc80, window: 0x5571ec08f330, parent: 0x5571ec08f4c0

# Copy from the application itself
Owner: 0x5571ec44de10, window: 0x5571ec08f330, parent: 0x5571ec08f4c0
```

I have tried comparing with the `Gtk::Application` toplevel window, or with the window of the `Gtk::Label` (`label->get_window()->gobj()`) that gets copied but none of the pointers match.